# numba `parallel=True` produces corrupted results

Tags: python, numpy, numba

**EDIT 2.**

It turns out the problem below is due to a bug in `numba` (version 0.54.1) which is now being examined by the Numba dev team. Here is the corresponding [GH issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7578).

========

I have a very simple Python/Numpy function and I want to compile it with Numba.

Everything works great for standard compilation, but if I use `parallel=True` then suddenly I get nonsensical corrupted data and I do not have a clue why.

Below is a reproducible example.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(boundscheck=False, nogil=True, parallel=False)
def ubcm_jacobian(
    D: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Jacobian of UBCM negative log-likelihood.

    Parameters
    ----------
    D
        Degree sequence array.
    b
        Model parameters.
    """
    B = np.empty_like(b)
    b = np.exp(b)

    for i in prange(len(b)):
        bi   = b[i]
        x    = bi * b
        B[i] = (x / (1 + x)).sum()

    b2 = b**2
    B -= b2 / (1 + b2)

    return B - D
```

Above is the function and below is simple data for which the error should reproduce.

```
D = np.arange(1, 11)
b = np.log(D)

ubcm_jacobian(D, b).sum()   # correct result: 28.9899 (roughly)
```

But if I compile the above function with `parallel=True` then I get nonsensical results, basically as if `B` array was not populated with values within the main loop.

And this is surprising because the whole routine seems to be trivially parallelizable. So what am I doing wrong?

======
Below I add the output of parallel diagnostics produced by Numba (it seems to be fine?)

```
================================================================================
 Parallel Accelerator Optimizing:  Function ubcm_jacobian, <ipython-
input-128-8dd321ee9df4> (1)  
================================================================================


Parallel loop listing for  Function ubcm_jacobian, <ipython-input-128-8dd321ee9df4> (1) 
----------------------------------------------------------|loop #ID
@njit(boundscheck=False, nogil=True, parallel=True)       | 
def ubcm_jacobian(                                        | 
    D: np.ndarray,                                        | 
    b: np.ndarray                                         | 
) -> np.ndarray:                                          | 
    """Jacobian of UBCM negative log-likelihood.          | 
                                                          | 
    Parameters                                            | 
    ----------                                            | 
    D                                                     | 
        Degree sequence array.                            | 
    b                                                     | 
        Model parameters.                                 | 
    """                                                   | 
    B = np.empty_like(b)                                  | 
    b = np.exp(b)-----------------------------------------| #39
                                                          | 
    for i in prange(len(b)):------------------------------| #46
        bi   = b[i]                                       | 
        x    = bi * b-------------------------------------| #40
        B[i] = (x / (1 + x)).sum()------------------------| #41, 45
                                                          | 
    b2 = b**2---------------------------------------------| #42
    B -= b2 / (1 + b2)------------------------------------| #43, 47
                                                          | 
    return B - D------------------------------------------| #44
------------------------------ After Optimisation ------------------------------
Parallel region 0:
+--39 (parallel)
   +--40 (serial, fused with loop(s): 41, 45)


 
Parallel region 0 (loop #39) had 2 loop(s) fused and 1 loop(s) serialized as 
part of the larger parallel loop (#39).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**

After updating to the latest `numba` version (`0.54.1`) the changed but it is still not correct. Now with `parallel=True` I get a result which is much closer to the correct one given by the function compiled with `parallel=False`, but it is still not correct. More concretely, now I get roughly `31.99498` but the correct answer is `28.9899`.

So still, something is not working.

Comment: There must be some race condition, but can't see why. If you remove `.sum()` you will see that results change every time you run `ubcm_jacobian` (with `parallel=True`)

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I think it is a good idea to an issue about this on the Numba git.

Comment: Thanks! I will file a report then.

Comment: I indeed is a bug according to the Numba team. I added a link to the corresponding GH issue in case anyone is interested in how this story develops.